# Can I use Surprise to predict ratings of new users on the fly?

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

Likely a quite trivial question:

I am using Python Surprise to build a classic recommender system. I have a training dataset that I can use to build my model. Once trained, I would like to predict ratings that users will give to items. These users are new to the system, so they are not in my training set. I would like to generate recommendations for them on the fly after they have rated a few items and without re-training the model.

So basically my code is:

```
from surprise import SVD
trainset = data.build_full_trainset()
svd = SVD(verbose=True, n_epochs=10)
svd.fit(trainset)
res = svd.predict(uid=5, iid="0")
```

But instead of predicting the user with uid=5 from the data set, I would like to add a new user and a few ratings given by that user and then predict other ratings for that user. Is that possible in general and in particular with Surprise?